# Create shortcut on apps menu for web application

Tags: android, jquery, ios, intel-xdk

I've built a small web application for mobile devices using Intel XDK and jQuery.

I think not but, I would like to ask to make sure if it where possible to programmatically create a shortcut in the device's applications menu that would take the user to the address of the mobile application.

Is that possible?

Thank you.

Comment: they have to manually add

Comment: Check this 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22167594/create-a-android-launch-icon-for-website

Comment: @rana_sapient Yes but that requires the user to create the shortcut, I was wondering if I could automatize it through jQuery, some HTML5 definition or some other method.

Comment: check this....http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html. This is pretty simple.