# Android Chrome Website icon is missing

Tags: android, google-chrome

I want to [Create a Android launch icon for Website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22167594/create-a-android-launch-icon-for-website) , but in Windows based chrome URL icon comes , which is missing  in Android's Chrome 'Add to HomeScreen'.For timgoolfiger.com that icon is missing in Android please help to find what's wrong.

Please find the attached images,
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quoting the [Add to Homescreen documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/installtohomescreen#icon):

> **Icon**
>
> The icon that is used to install to the homescreen is determined by
>   using the largest icon found in one of the following  tags:
>
> - `<link rel="icon" sizes="192x192" href="nice-highres.png">`    (recommended)
> - `<link rel="icon" sizes="128x128" href="niceicon.png">`
> - `<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="128x128" href="niceicon.png">`
> - `<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="128x128" href="niceicon.png">`
>
> **Caution:** The 192px image format is recommended. The last two formats (`apple-touch-*`) are deprecated, and will be supported only for a short time.

Comment: Thanks for answer,but why it is not acceptiing this  image,<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/home/favicon.ico">
there is not specific rel attribute.

Comment: You should provide a better quality icon, at least 128x128 in png format. You can try with the stackoverflow's image: `http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png`