# "bookmark this site" button for mobile devices

Tags: android, jquery, iphone, html, mobile

I am creating a mobile webpage using jquery mobile, no luck in creating a button when tapping which will create a home page icon automatically, a one tap process, on both ios and android devices, something like the AddFavorite() function in the desktop world, is it technically possible ?

Comment: While jQuery Mobile is mentioned this question doesn't have anything to do with jQuery Mobile.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21018750/645270) thread might have some relevant info